# How do you get the middle result from a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database, which has a collection that contains all of the addresses from a country. Sometimes when I execute a query on that I have a chance that I receive about 200 results (house numbers within that street). I want to get the middle item of that result.

When I do that in my coding like this for example:

```
const result = Address.find({ street: "fooStreet" })
// results in an array with a length of let's say 200 (could also be 20, 49, 103, etc) items
```

I could split it in my coding like below:

```
const middleIndex = Math.round(result.length / 2);
const house = result[middleIndex];
```

But this means that the other records go to waste and use unnecessary bandwidth + computing power which should be handled by the database. Since the database OS is optimized for working with collections etc, I was wondering if I could achieve the same result in a mongodb query? See pseudo below:

```js
db.getCollection("addresses")
  .find({ street: "fooStreet" }) 
  .helpMeHere()
  // ^ do something to get the middle result from the N items
```

Comment: Are you looking for `$skip` and `$limit` which gets you the number of records you want from any position?

Comment: @Gibbs I'm pretty sure it's variable since it's **about** 200 records, so you won't really know how much to skip and limit

Comment: Do you always want to get the result from middle? 50% and above?

Comment: @Gibbs Yes, I would always like to have the middle from the result. The result can be 20 items in length aswell as 200 items. I would always like to have the exact middle (so for 200 the 100/101, for 20 the 10/11). So the length is unknown but I want the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { //Any match condition
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {//get the total matching result
      "_id": null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 0.5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {//get the second half
      "result": {
        "$slice": [
          "$data",
          {
            "$toInt": {
              "$multiply": [//Negating results records from the last
                {
                  "$toInt": "$count"
                },
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z-gUZDB56fV)

To get one element:

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wQqs3aRMeE9)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 0.5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "result": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [//array access
          "$data",
          {
            "$toInt": "$count"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Close! But there should be a maximum of 1 result, so if I got `[ { a: 1 }, { a: 2}, { a: 3 }, { a: 4}, { a: 5} ]` I would like to only get `{ a: 3 }` for example

Comment: Why sum of 0.5 ?

Comment: To get middle, i made use of $sum to avoid $divide later @KunalMukherjee